# Count children + change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to dynamically give child A tags an even width based on the number of tags contained in a list. (eg. if 4 A's they will all be 25% width, 3 tags they will be 33%).

I have tried counting the number of children inside the div and dividing 100 by the var number with no success

**jQuery**

```
 var numChildren = $("div a").size()
    $('a').css({ width : 100/numChildren });
```

**CSS**

```
a { width: /*DYNAMIC*/ (all even) }

div {width: 100%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: "The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead." - http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: A-tags are inline elements. Inline elements are the width of their content. You need to make them inline-block or block as well.

Comment: Yes i have them floated, however the list is always fluctuating with the number of elements therefore I need to dynamically assign a width for them to fit asthetically. For the sake of simplicity I put the bare minimum CSS/HTML up to put a focus on dynamically generated width

Comment: 100/numChildren is just a number. You need to give it UNITS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it CSS-only, without counting the number of elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.wrapper > a {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ePEy2/)

Comment: +1 Ahh, you beat me for 5 seconds, as I already had mine too ready http://jsfiddle.net/3WJp2/

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, if there are four elements, you are setting this:

```
width: 25;
```

I think you want this:

```
$('a').css({ width : 100/numChildren + '%' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pjRaJ/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
 <a></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:#888;
}

a{
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numberChild = $("#content a").length;
    $("#content a").css("width",(100/numberChild)+"%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the jquery to:

```
 var numChildren = $("div a").length;
    $('a').css({ 'width', 100/numChildren + '%' });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <a>Test Me</a>
 <a>Test Me</a>
 <a>Test Me</a>
 <a>Test Me</a>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var numChildren = $("div a").length;
$('a').css({ width : 100/numChildren+'%' });
alert(100/numChildren);
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
    width:300px;
}
a
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#EEE;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQFeh/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to set `width` in percentage. As you are ultimately going to use javascript to evenly distribute `width`

HTML:

```
<div>
 <a>One</a>
 <a>Two</a>
 <a>Three</a>
 <a>Four</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var parent =  $("div");
var anchors = parent.find('a');
anchors.css({ width : parent.width() / anchors.length });
```

CSS:

```
div > a {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4N8T6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Oriol's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19435134/607874) is the correct one, if you don't need to support [IE7 and below](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

If you need support for these browsers, you can calculate the relative width as others already explained.

But if you know that you will never have more than *n* children, you can also do:

```
// assuming that will never have more than 4 children
$('div:has(a)').addClass('one');
$('div:has(a+a)').addClass('two');
$('div:has(a+a+a)').addClass('three');
$('div:has(a+a+a+a)').addClass('four');
```

and the css

```
div a       { width: 100%; }
div.two a   { width: 50%; }
div.three a { width: 33.3%; }
div.four a  { width: 25%; }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3WJp2/2/)